# gpio-keys not working in combination with I/O expander driver gpio-pca953x (TCA6416A)

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, linux-device-driver, gpio, device-tree

I want to integrate/load the `gpio-pca953x` driver in my Raspberry Pi3 B+ Linux with the help of an DT overlay. This driver is a general I²C controlled I/O expander gpio driver for various chips i.e. TCA6416. I managed to create an dts overlay which enables the driver.

```dts
/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;
/ {
        compatible = "brcm,bcm2835", "brcm,bcm2708", "brcm,bcm2709";

        fragment@0 {
                target = <&i2c1>;
                __overlay__ {
                        status = "okay";
                };
        };

        fragment@1 {
                target = <&i2c1>;
                __overlay__ {
                        #address-cells = <1>;
                        #size-cells = <0>;

                        tca6416: tca6416@20 {
                                compatible = "ti,tca6416";
                                reg = <0x20>;
                                gpio-controller;
                                #gpio-cells = <2>;
                                interrupt-parent = <&gpio>;
                                interrupts = <18 0x02>; //IRQ_TYPE_EDGE_FALLING
                        };
                };
        };
};
```

There is a new gpiochip */sys/class/gpio/gpiochip488* and also interrupts seems to work.

I thought the next easy step would be to create a virtual input device with the help of the `gpio-keys` module. But it seems I was wrong.

I created another DT overlay like this:

```dts
    fragment@1 {
            target-path = "/soc";
            __overlay__ {
                    gpio: gpio-button {
                            compatible = "gpio-keys";
                            autorepeat;
                            button@14 {
                                    label = "TestKey";
                                    linux,code = <14>;
                                    gpios = <&tca6416 0 1>;
                            };
                    };
            };
    };
```

But this time this overlay can never be loaded. The error I got is always that symbol **tca6416** can not be found in live device tree symbol table. What am I doing wrong here? Are there any working examples? I also tried to replace **tca6416** in `gpios` above with **gpio488** or any other possible name. Neither works.

Comment: Was the first overlay compiled with the `-@` (or `--symbols`) command line option?

Comment: I compiled both with -@ option.

Comment: If you put them in one overlay, does it work?

Comment: I wonder if the symbols from the first overlay get adjusted to refer to the live tree, or if they still refer to `fragment@1` in the live tree. Could you list the live device tree on the system and check whether `tca6416` appears in the `__symbols__` node, and what it refers to?

Comment: No tca6416 doens't apper in `__symbols__` in the live tree. After many more tests I managed to find a working solution, but by not using the overlays but modifying dts file instead. I will change my post accordingly soon. It **COULD** be a naming problem,  tca6416: tca6416@20 should be  tca6416_20: tca6416@20 my first tests showed that at least.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem is the DTS overlay mechanism it self in some way. `tca6416` gets never export as symbol in live tree. My solution is **not** using the overlay but including an DTS file in one of the main DTS files like `bcm2710-rpi-3-b-plus.dts` instead.

This include file contains:

```dts
&i2c1 {
      tca6416_20: tca6416@20 {
              compatible = "ti,tca6416";
              #gpio-cells = <2>;
              reg = <0x20>;
              gpio-controller;
              interrupt-parent = <&gpio>;
              interrupts = <18 IRQ_TYPE_EDGE_FALLING>;
              reset-gpios = <&gpio 23 GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW>;
      };
};
```

This works as intended so does `gpio-keys`.